# IOREF default voltage reference circuit with two NPN transistors

Tags: arduino, transistors, npn, voltage-reference, voltage-source

I'm trying to build a small circuit to sense when a voltage ref (for IO output) is supplied otherwise set a default voltage reference.

A bit of context - This is common within the Arduino ecosystem where shields should accept a IOREF input that indicates the attached board IO voltage level. I'm basically trying to to hook this input to a bi-directional level shifter (to one side of the voltage inputs) and whenever there is no input I want a fixed voltage to be applied (internal 3.3v).

Here is my attempt to achieve that using two 2n3904 NPN transistors and one diode.

- The switches mimics the IOREF input (3.3v | 5V or none)
- The voltmeter is the input of the voltage side on the level shifter.
- The upper 3.3v is the default I want taken from an internal voltage regulator.

Q1 - While it seems it should work I'm worried about voltage drops caused by the IOREF transistor and the diode on the default voltage input - I will use use low Vf components and I can probably get a way with a small voltage drop but I wonder if I can avoid that???

Q2 - Should I place a pull down resistor on the base of the IOREF npn transistor?

Q3 - Should I place a resistor to ground on the emitter side of the "DEF" npn transistor?

Q4 - Do you see any problem with this circuit????

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the 'voltage side on the level shifter'? What is the intended purpose of the upper transistor?

Comment: @BruceAbbott On a bi-directional level shifting IC such as the 8-Bit TXS0108EPWR you supply it with two Vcc (A & B) those are used for the output of each side. I'm trying to feed the IOREF voltage to it to get the correct output or if that pin is not connected I want a fixed 3.3V and thats why I have a second (upper transistor) which will pass the 3.3v whenever the switch (IOREF pin) is low or not connected.

Comment: The upper transistor is shorting the 3.3V regulated supply to ground (drawing 101mA in the 3rd configuration). Doesn't appear to be a useful function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to avoid the voltage drop, assuming the average current draw from the Vcc_B is modest:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fufkA9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>